# Hibernate Session handling

Tags: java, hibernate, session, wicket

Im trying to learn hibernate and wicket. Im actually not sure when to open and close a hibernate session. I´ve searched a lot and read many things about the session factory, but I still dont get it.

I want to get some data of my database and show it in a table in the browser. That actually works if im the first time on that site, but if I use the back button and go onto that site again it shows me this error:

```
Last cause: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
```

I think its because I close my SessionFactory to early or something like that. But I dont know how to solve the problem.

My Java Class:

```
public class CategoryPanel extends Panel {
    private WebMarkupContainer categoryContainer;
    public CategoryPanel(String id) {
        super(id);
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = DbFactory.getSessionFactory();                  // creating the Session Factory     
        StandardDao<Category> categoryDao = StandardDao.getInstance(sessionFactory);    // creating dao to access data
        List<Category> categoryList = categoryDao.getAll(Category.class);               // get data of the db  
        CategoryDataProvider dataProvider = new CategoryDataProvider(categoryList);        
        categoryContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("categoryTable");

        final DataView dv = new DataView("categoryList", dataProvider) {

          @Override
          protected void populateItem(Item item) {
              final Category category = (Category) item.getModelObject();
              final CompoundPropertyModel<Category> categoryModel = new     CompoundPropertyModel<Category>(category);

              item.add(new Label("catTitle", categoryModel.bind("title")));
          }
         };
        categoryContainer.add(new Label("categoryTitle", Model.of("Titel")));
        add(categoryContainer);
        sessionFactory.close(); // here I close the factory, this seems to be wrong. I dont know if i close it anyway..
    }
}
```

My Dao:

```
public class StandardDao<T> {
 private static StandardDao instance = null;
    private static final Object syncObject = new Object();
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    private StandardDao(SessionFactory session){
     this.sessionFactory = session;
    }

     public static StandardDao getInstance(SessionFactory session) {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (syncObject) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new StandardDao(session);
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }   
        public List<T> getAll( Class theClass) {
            List<T> entity = null;
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            try {
                entity = session.createCriteria(theClass).list();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
            session.flush();
            // if I close the session here, I cant load lazy
         }
            return entity;
         }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not close a SessionFactory. The SessionFactory is used to return you a Session, on which you work and the close only the Session.

Moreover, you usually don't open and close the session inside controller code, but delegate this handling to an external component that can open a new session from the session factory every time a request arrive, and most importantly close it only when the request is finished, meaning also the view part has done it's work.

This pattern is usually called "Open Session in View".

In a Java web server this usually done with a servlet filter, that you configure in your web.xml.

Search Google for Java Open Session in View filter and you'll find plenty of examples and explanations.